# Cant find resolution for the error "invalid conversion from char to const char*"

Tags: c++, string, char, border, constants

I have looked around but cant find an answer to my question. The program is suppose to put a border of stars (`*`) around a heading, but I'm getting the error:

```
invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

as well as the error

```
initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]|
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
string name;
cin >> name;

//Build the message that we intend to write
const string greeting = "Hello " + name + "!";

//Build the second and fourth line of the output
const string spaces = (greeting.size(), ' ');
const string second = "* " + spaces + " *";

//Build the first and fifth lines of the output
const string first = "* " + spaces + " *";

//Write all the output
cout << endl;
cout << first << endl;
cout << second << endl;
cout << "* " << greeting << " *" << endl;
cout << second << endl;
cout << first << endl;

return 0;
}
```

That's the code to print out the border around the heading ^^ (relating to the first error).

```
// TBD: DPG annotate
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
*Error ->* basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a)
: _M_dataplus(_S_construct(__s, __s ? __s + traits_type::length(__s) :
               __s + npos, __a), __a)
{ }
```

That is the code relating to the second error ^^ (which is in the string function).

I put both bits of code because I don't know which is caused by which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
const string spaces = (greeting.size(), ' ');
```

should be

```
const string spaces(greeting.size(), ' ');
```

With `=`, it attempts to initialise `spaces` with the result of the expression `(greeting.size(), ' ')`. That expression uses the *comma operator*, which evaluates and discards `greeting.size()`, and gives `' '` as its result; so it's equivalent to

```
const string spaces = ' ';
```

trying to initialise `string` with a single character, when there's no suitable constructor to do that.

Removing `=`, it's initialised using two constructor arguments, giving a string containing the requested number of spaces.